# Jib: set repository depending on maven profile

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, jhipster, jib

I have an app where I want to push to repository `A` or `B` depending on the profile that is being run.

For instance:

If I run this in Jenkins `sh "./mvnw package -Pint verify -DskipTests jib:dockerBuild"` it should push to our integration registry.

If I run this in Jenkins `sh "./mvnw package -Pprod verify -DskipTests jib:dockerBuild"` it should push to our production repository.

I've set up my pom like this:

```
<from>
    <image>adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot</image>
</from>
<to>
    <image>${docker.repository.url}/${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</image>
    <tags>
        <tag>${project.version}-${spring.profiles.active}-${git.commit.id.abbrev}</tag>
    </tags>
</to>
```

How do I get it to behave in this particular way?

Comment: Hey! Are you asking how to have different properties values depending on a profile? (e.g. different `docker.repository.url`

Comment: There's a lot going on here. I think you need to share more of your pom with us. Especially the `<profiles>` section of your pom.

Comment: @Augusto yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy :D. You only need to define a `<properties>` section inside the  `<profile>` section. These properties will be added  when you run the specified profile (and I have the strong feeling it does override any property set in the global `<properties>` section).

For example:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>int</id>
      <properties>
        <docker.repository.url>https://your.docker.registry</docker.repository.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

There is a bit more information on the [profiles documentation page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#profiles-in-poms), in particular which elements can be used inside a profile.